# how to submit recaptcha using post data

Tags: php, httpwebrequest, http-post, captcha, recaptcha

I can't figure out what url to post data to for google recpatcha.

for example I can go to my website http://www.winfreebitcoin.co/login.php
and then I can get the public key which is 6LcujwETAAAAAFVu4q6R8F0dfQEroEpeP2YIWViS

and then go to

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcujwETAAAAAFVu4q6R8F0dfQEroEpeP2YIWViS
```

to get the challenge

I then can go to something like this to get the image

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/image?c=03AHJ_VuvRj66zfLX3gox2JRbzpnhXheEo7PeAXLjbG07ezT-GPRWT9jj6lihszM6odlUIB7Bkd60unQAJII61Fau9tMfLR0A290U1e2_o1oU-e1qgm15uyHMS4YBt8vonrUn2qLqBAvcpyUS1lb83tvwW8O6x_iaXTEPRTdzgCGcBP5_EHHNvvmjeVpT1Q5_2xLyJaNg6sJwnouwW43G5m_zr_7nw2b9Vrhya16TPbR2kEBCb1OnjVPbDvJB33ddZQsdo1Pm9EnHS
```

my question is after I get the image, how can I send the data back to the page so that the captcha is redeemed?

I know your supposed to post the field 
recaptcha_challenge_field    and
recaptcha_response_field

but I don't know where to post it to

I have tried the site the captcha form is on

```
http://www.winfreebitcoin.co/login.php
```

the main site

```
http://www.winfreebitcoin.co/
```

and the google captcha public key

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcujwETAAAAAFVu4q6R8F0dfQEroEpeP2YIWViS
```

and none of these seem to work

here is the url with the posted data, so maybe I am doing this wrong?

```
http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/challenge?k=6LcujwETAAAAAFVu4q6R8F0dfQEroEpeP2YIWViS&recaptcha_challenge_field=03AHJ_Vusq-MxDZ3y5S8VSMeFxXp_Dmw5zq1T39PCin3I9d5pXYWVCaGh0uURBJ3szrzeN_C1kbBT4WSeCl3dlP4v9r5-rNb7bzUDgBvzViYEnH3_5p6pCSn7jY1lqO1DR_45GcIAm67dDmBqSdeDtvkPY2ESvMMcmDDIgCQ5Pr_HnGOqgi_XZYm88fCUUCQY2EEbBdEok74CG5DGg_iNjb2Md09bAYab8wOtQLPPWi6SfNAPTcuDrR4iXVWnJs1bJSOtDqQceW0-R&recaptcha_response_field=trlynac
```

can anyone show me how to submit the google captcha and what the url is to post the data to?

Thanks

**UPDATE**
I am mainly going to use this for collecting bitcoin from sites, so I really cant use a php script, my bot is in vb.net

Comment: I am still not understanding, for the above example do I have to send the username and password as well. what if the site does not have a username and password.

Answer (score 2):

You should validate it like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=YOUR_SECRET_HERE&response='.$_POST['g-recaptcha-response'].'&remoteip='.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$res = json_decode($res);

if($res->success != 1)
    die('wrong recaptcha');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am using this for a bitcoin faucet bot, so how would I get the secret from the website, or is this just the sitekey

Comment: The secret you don't need to get - it is private and only you should know it. Just hardcode it...